# Safe executing shell scripts; escaping vars before execution

Tags: php, security, shell

Let's imagine that we have a simple php script that should get `ssh_host`, `ssh_username`, `ssh_port` from $_GET array and try to connect using this parameters to SSH.

```
$port      = escapeshellcmd($_GET['ssh_port']);
$host      = escapeshellcmd($_GET['ssh_host']);
$username  = escapeshellcmd($_GET['ssh_username']);

$answer = shell_exec("ssh -p " . $port . " " . $user . "@" . $host);
```

Is `escapeshellcmd()` enough or I need something more tricky?
Or maybe I should use `escapeshellarg()` in this example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that this is what the [**`escapeshellarg`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) function has been created for -- so, to escape parameters, that's the one you should be using.

Basically :

- To escape one parameter, use [`escapeshellarg`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)
- And to escape a command as a whole, use [`escapeshellcmd`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php).

Quoting their respective documentations :

**escapeshellcmd() :**

This function should be used to make sure that any data coming from user input is escaped before this data is passed to the `exec()` or `system()`  functions, or to the backtick operator. 


**escapeshellarg() :**

This function should be used to escape **individual arguments** to shell functions coming from user input.