# pass $_SERVER array through php exec function

Tags: php, exec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Safe executing shell scripts; escaping vars before execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624616/safe-executing-shell-scripts-escaping-vars-before-execution)

I want to pass `$_SERVER` data through php `exec()` function to run another script for background process.
to pass a simple parameter I do it like this:

```
exec("/usr/bin/php -f bg.php parameter1 > /dev/null &");
```

But I think it is impossible to directly pass an array to this function. So I tried *`serialize($_SERVER)`* . but now there's a bigger problem. Characters like quotations,  semicolons and many others break down the shell command and it doesn't work properly.

So what's the solution to solve this problem?

Comment: have you tried simply enclosing the serialized array in quotes? this strategy has worked for me: `exec("/usr/bin/php -f bg.php '".serialize($_SERVER)."' parameter2 > /dev/null &");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe what you are looking for is: http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: you mean I should use it after serialize($_SERVER) ?

Comment: yes, the serialized string should be passed to it.